# Private Key/Public Key (SSL certificate) to setup an Amazon EC2 Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I am trying to create an Elastic Load Balancer, but I am unable to get the information (private key and public key certificate) to validate through the AWS console. 
I keep receiving private key/public key mismatch.

Digicert provides the cert in a .p7b file format. Besides the p7b certificate I have a file.pem with the private key (-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----) and a keystore file. 
I use both everytime i launch one amazon ec2 instance.
Is it possible to extract the public key from those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be the keystore file that you used to generate the actual certificate. Not the one you use to login to the server.

See [This](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=53100)

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by the @chantheman does not exust anymore.
So here is the solution:you need 2 files:
**mycompany.p7b** (certificate file) and
**mycompany_private.key** (private key file)

```
#!/bin/bash
# convert p7b to cer
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in mycompany.p7b -out mycompany.cer
# convert cer to pfx
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycompany.cer -inkey mycompany_private.key -out mycompany.pfx
# extract data from pfx
mkdir aws
openssl pkcs12 -in mycompany.pfx -nocerts -nodes | sed -ne '/-BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-/,/-END PRIVATE KEY-/p' > aws/private.key
openssl pkcs12 -in mycompany.pfx -clcerts -nokeys | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > aws/certificate.cer
openssl pkcs12 -in mycompany.pfx -cacerts -nokeys -chain | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > aws/chain.cer
```

In a result you should have 3 files:

- private.key (copy it’s content to AWS ‘Certificate private key’
- field) certificate.cer (copy it’s content to AWS ‘Certificate bBody’
- field) chain.cer (copy it’s content to AWS ‘Certificate chain’ field)